# Why Invoke is needed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I kinda do understand point of threads and invokes, but not so great. I'm having server/client application made from tutorial. Now I'm having 2 functions. In Disconnect function I need to have Invoke but in Received function I don't.

Why is that (problem is lstClient) ?

And if I have Invoke in Received function then Invoke is just looping for some reason, why?

```
void client_Disconnected(Client sender)
{
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lstClient.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Client client = lstClient.Items[i].Tag as Client;
            if(client.ID == sender.ID)
            {
                lb_ID.Items.RemoveAt(i); lb_ip.Items.RemoveAt(i); lb_users.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                lstClient.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}

void client_Received(Client sender, byte[] data)
{
    /*Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {*/
        for (int i = 0; i < lstClient.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Client client = lstClient.Items[i].Tag as Client;
            if (client.ID == sender.ID)
            {
                if (Encoding.Default.GetString(data) == "end") 
                {
                    client_Disconnected(client); 
                    break;
                }
                lstClient.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
                lstClient.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text = DateTime.Now.ToString() ;
                break;
            }
        }
    //});
}
```

Comment: It's a matter of whether the method is executed on the main thread or not. I don't know how you're using those methods and your code logic, but the snippet suggests that the Received is running on the UI thread, while the DCed is running on a different thread (and I'm not saying that this makes sense). Regardless, the Invoke is required due to touching UI business (from different thread), so if you had different logic you might not have needed to use Invoke in either of those methods.

Comment: @YoryeNathan About threads, how can I know when something is running on main thread and when not ? When does this happen, is something in code or is just how this works ?

Comment: The code itself indicates on what threads things run. If you're lazy, you can just set a breakpoint in the method and open the Threads tab in Debug, and see where you at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how the method is called.

There is a property InvokeRequired property on some objects (Controls) that can be used to selectively invoke when needed.

In a WinForms application, any method that changes the form will have to be run within the Form UI thread to avoid conflicts but any method that makes no changes could often safely be called without invoke but it could get partial results.

Comment: Calling the UI thread the "Form main thread" might be a bit misleading. I get the sense that each form may have its own main thread. It might be better to just say "UI thread" instead.

Comment: Also, it's not safe to have code that makes "no changes" (i.e. reading UI elements) running on another thread. To be certain that UI code runs correctly it must be run on the UI thread - for all read and write operations.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a painful, but even "get partial results" could be wrong. There's no guarantee that what appears to be a read-only operation might update something internally. It would be easy to write code that does that. We don't know what the framework code is doing. Also, it is possible to have a race condition where a purely read-only operation would return not a "partial" result, but a completely incorrect result. The bottom-line is you cannot safely do any operation on a non-UI-thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity no, there is only ever one UI thread and it handles all forms and controls.

Comment: @Andy - Yes, I know. I was just commenting that the wording in this answer was potentially misleading for others.